# How do I go about automatically grabbing a csv file from this website?

Tags: javascript, python, csv

There is this website:

https://www.aemo.com.au/Electricity/National-Electricity-Market-NEM/Data-dashboard#price-demand

that has some information I want to utilise for a project.

In the top right there is a little download button that allows users to download a nice csv file that I can open in my code.

My question is how I would go about automatically downloading this data from my python program.

I have tried to inspect the download button element and under "Event Listeners" in Chrome there is a .js file that executes when the download button is pressed:

https://www.aemo.com.au/aemo/apps/visualisations/dist/aurelia-24ac75bb54.js

I'm just not too sure how to link it all together so I can automatically grab the csv file every 5-10 minutes.

I was hoping that someone could help me!

Thanks

Comment: look at the network tab in developer tools - the links for the data are https://www.aemo.com.au/aemo/apps/api/report/5MIN and https://www.aemo.com.au/aemo/apps/api/report/ELEC_NEM_SUMMARY

Comment: Okay I see these in Chrome. How do I go about sending a request from say a python script? When I open the link in Chrome it is just a blank page. When I look at it from the network tab I can see the request format and that makes sense.

Comment: sorry, that would be a python question, I only came here for the javascript :p

Comment: No worries. I think you have put me on the right track! Thank you very much Jaromanda X!

Answer (score 0):

just use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and go through the documentation.

or else [selenium webdriver](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html) would definitely help you out.